# How to test code inside a while loop that only executes based on a random number generator?

Tags: python, unit-testing, while-loop, pytest

So I have this function:

```
def gen_poly(n,q):
    l = 0.0 #Gamma Distribution Location (Mean "center" of dist.)
    poly = np.floor(np.random.normal(loc=l, size=(n)))
    while (len(poly) < n):
        poly = np.floor(np.random.normal(loc=l, size=(n)))
        poly = np.floor(p.polydiv(poly, xN_1)[1]%q)
    return poly
```

This generates a polynomial of length n with random numbers. However, sometimes, it will generate less than n values (specifically n - 1 values). So the while loop is there incase this happens and if it does, it repeats the random polynomial generation until it does become of length n.
I need to create a unit test case specifically for the code inside the while loop. Is there anyway I can force the code inside the while loop to execute? maybe repeatedly call the function until the while loop executes.
I've a number of other functions with the same issue so If I can figure this out, i can create test cases for them too

Can't think of what way to approach this problem. It would be different if the while loop depended on an input paramater but it completely depends on the random() function.

EDIT: Sorry, there was a typo in the original. It doesn't append 0 to the end, it just repeats the random polynomial generation until it becomes of length n

Comment: Ultimately, you *don't* want random values: you want a sequence of values known or selected ahead of time. You can do that by either seeding the random number generator with a fixed value just before the test runs, or by patching `np.random.normal` to produces values from a fixed sequence.

Comment: @chepner Unfortunately, it has to be random. Its for an assignment and that's what it asks for. It is annoying to be honest

Comment: That doesn't prevent you from extracting the random data to parameters. More specifically, you're trying to test an algorithm here, not that random data is actually random

Answer (score 2):

Extract the two lines within the while loop

```
def regen_poly(poly, n, q, l=0.0):  # add more parameters, as needed 
    if len(poly) < n:
        poly = np.floor(np.random.normal(loc=l, size=(n)))
        poly = np.floor(p.polydiv(poly, xN_1)[1]%q)
    return poly

def gen_poly(n,q):
    l = 0.0 #Gamma Distribution Location (Mean "center" of dist.)
    poly = np.floor(np.random.normal(loc=l, size=(n)))
    while len(poly) < n:
        poly = regen_poly(poly, n, q, l)
    return poly
```

Then test `regen_poly` based on different size inputs if they return the same output as input, or not

> force the code inside the while loop to execute

Extract poly to a parameter, as shown. Don't use random values for tests

Going further, you could pass a "regeneration function" handle into `gen_poly`, then you could assert the number of times it would be called in the loop for different inputs

```
def gen_poly(data, n, q, regen):
    poly = np.floor(data)
    while len(poly) < n:
        poly = regen(poly, n, q, l)
    return poly

l = 0.0 #Gamma Distribution Location (Mean "center" of dist.)
# or non random data 
data = np.random.normal(loc=l, size=(n))
# or mock/stub function 
f = regen_poly
poly = gen_poly(data, n, q, f)
```